# View and Edit Use case

Tags: uml, use-case

[image]

I've got a snippet out of my use case diagram (refer to figure). I'm not sure how to arrange `View account details` use case. In order to edit an account Agent must first open account details (as pictured above). Then he can proceed to actually change account details.

But what if the agent only wants to check account details, should I initiate View account details (as pictured), or is it enough to execute Edit Account Details up to the point of actually performing an edit and then stopping?

Comment: The above mentioned diagram is right from my point of view, when you consider your second statement mentioned above. You need to initiate View Account Details separately.

Comment: I usually tend to include all CRUD actions into one "Manage Account Details" use case, Create, Read, Update and Delete then become scenario in this use case. But as @Vivek mentioned, from a UML the link between Agent and View Account Details is correct. I'm just not sure about your Repository Actor. Actors are always external to the system you are describing. "Repository" sounds awfully like an part of your system rather then an external system.

Comment: @GeertBellekens, Repository is DB actually, but there are different DBs that we're querying (the real diagram is a bit more complex than this). So I just simplified the whole thing and condensed these DB's as Repository.

Comment: @Robotron In most cases we consider the database as being a part of the system, even if there are more then one databases.

Comment: @GeertBellekens Personally, I usually model the database as another actor.  To call the database part of the system implies that the database's functionality is limited to the use cases that the system describes, and a database will typically interact with any number of systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question, based on the description of the use cases, is yes.  The reason that you are having trouble conceptually is because you are placing an include relationship between view account details and edit account details.  (You are actually saying that edit account details always includes view account details, which is probably true, but that doesn't get at what you are trying to model.)

The way to model this out is to change your includes to an extends.  This means that while you will always view account details, you may or may not edit them as well.  In that case, also, the Agent actor will interact with view but only indirectly with edit, as a consequence of extending the view use case.

So, change include to extend, and remove the association bar between agent and the edit use case.

p. s. If you don't like putting a human for the Repository actor, you can always put a rectangle with the << actor >> stereotype above it.

Answer (score 1):

UseCase definition says that system during the UseCase execution collaborates (interacts) with external entities (Actors). I think that "View Account Details" UseCase involve interaction with Agent. It is correct to connect this usecase with Agent actor.

By the way, by your diagram, system can execute "View Account Details" without execution of "Edit Account Details". So, Agent should be connected to UseCase if there is some kind of interaction with system and Agent.

Comment: The thing that confuses me here is that when the screen for View... is shown, all the fields will be editable. In my mind it seems as if Edit is just an extension of View. So going from View to Edit is really easy, agent just updates a few fields and stores that. So I'm not sure if perhaps I should remove Agent-Edit link and change the <<include>> into <<extends>> (and keep the same orientation)?
I know this is opposite of my initial question, but my perception of this problem is changing the more I think about it.

Comment: Try to find precise information about how usecases are defined in UML Superstructure document. www.uml.org

Comment: @Robotron: I noticed this note after I answered your question.  It looks like you figured it out on your own!  :)  An easy way to keep track of includes vs. extends is that includes are always done, and extends are optional.